# Issue with python class in Kodi, trying to write a UI to replace Kodi generic menu with PYXBMCT

Tags: python, class, kodi

I'm quite new to python class's and have not really used them much so please feel free to point out any other errors except the one I point out.

What I'm trying to achieve is a new `UI in Kodi` using the `pyxbmct` module. I'm sending through a list of things (still yet to work out how I'm going to sort the split to next process with the modes but that's the next task)

My Lists are as such:

```
List = [['[COLOR darkgoldenrod][I]Search[/I][/COLOR]','',904,'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icontexto/search/256/search-red-dark-icon.png','','',''],
['[COLOR darkgoldenrod][I]Menu Test[/I][/COLOR]','',905,'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icontexto/search/256/search-red-dark-icon.png','','','']]
process.Window_Menu_Class(List)
```

Then obviously being sent through to the Window_Menu_Class() to attempt to display the name(s) in a List and also display a icon to the right but alternating depending on where you are focused in the List.

Code for Window_Menu_Class :-

```
import pyxbmct
List = []

class Window_Menu_Class():

    fanart = 'http://www.wall321.com/thumbnails/detail/20121108/creepy%20video%20games%20castles%20diablo%20tristram%20creep%20diablo%20iii%20sanctuary%201920x1080%20wallpaper_www.wall321.com_92.jpg'
    iconimage = ICON
    power = 'http://herovision.x10host.com/fb_replays/power.png'
    power_focus = 'http://herovision.x10host.com/fb_replays/power_focus.png'
    text = '0xffffffff'
    window_menu  = pyxbmct.AddonDialogWindow('')
    Background=pyxbmct.Image(fanart)
    Icon=pyxbmct.Image('', aspectRatio=2)
    button = pyxbmct.Button('', noFocusTexture=power,focusTexture=power_focus)
    window_menu.setGeometry(1250, 650, 100, 50)
    nameList = pyxbmct.addonwindow.List(_space=11,_itemTextYOffset=0,textColor=text)
    window_menu.connect(button, window_menu.close)
    window_menu.connect(pyxbmct.ACTION_NAV_BACK, window_menu.close)
    window_menu.placeControl(Background, -5, 0, 110, 51)
    window_menu.placeControl(nameList, 65, 1, 50, 20)
    window_menu.placeControl(Icon, 30, 30, 60, 18)    
    name_list = [];    url_list = [];    mode_list = [];    iconimage_list = [];    fanart_list = [];    desc_list = [];    extra_list = []

def __init__(self,List):
    self.Window_Menu(List)

def Window_Menu(self,List):
    for item in List:
        name = item[0]
        url = item[1]
        mode = item[2]
        iconimage = item[3]
        fanart = item[4]
        desc = item[5]
        extra = item[6]
        if not name in self.name_list:
            self.nameList.addItem(name);self.name_list.append(name);self.url_list.append(url);self.mode_list.append(mode);self.iconimage_list.append(iconimage);self.fanart_list.append(fanart);self.desc_list.append(desc);self.extra_list.append(extra)
            self.create_window(name,url,mode,iconimage,fanart,desc,extra)
    self.window_menu.doModal()


def create_window(self,name,url,mode,iconimage,fanart,desc,extra):
    self.window_menu.setFocus(self.nameList)
    self.window_menu.connectEventList(
    [pyxbmct.ACTION_MOVE_DOWN,
    pyxbmct.ACTION_MOVE_UP,
    pyxbmct.ACTION_MOUSE_MOVE],
    self.LIST_UPDATE(name,url,mode,iconimage,fanart,desc,extra))


def LIST_UPDATE(self,name,url,mode,iconimage,fanart,desc,extra):
    if self.window_menu.getFocus() == self.nameList:
        pos=self.nameList.getSelectedPosition()
        Iconimg=self.iconimage_list[pos]
        Fanart =self.fanart_list[pos]
        self.Icon.setImage(Iconimg)
        self.Background.setImage(Fanart)
```

but I receive the error -

File "C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\addons\plugin.video.sanctuary\lib\process.py", line 74, in LIST_UPDATE
                                                if self.window_menu.getFocus() == self.nameList:
                                            RuntimeError: Non-Existent Control 0

If I hash out the `if self.window_menu.getFocus() == self.nameList:` then it works but, it doesn't alter the image in the list when you move on to the next item, I have a working version but it was all done in one .py file and no need for class at all, however now I am trying to separate the code into different .py files i needed to create a class to contain all the info and give a starting point.  Hope this is enough information and appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does not have a simple answer because you are doing it wrong at both Python level and PyXBMCt level (I'm the author of PyXBMCt, BTW).

First, I strongly recommend you to learn Python classes: how they are defined, how they are initialized, how they are used.

When you get that in order, then I strongly recommend to read PyXBMCt documentation which is now hosted here: http://romanvm.github.io/script.module.pyxbmct/ Look into the examples, including the example plugin, that show how to use PyXBMCt. For example, what is this `window_menu.placeControl(Background, -5, 0, 110, 51)`? PyXBMCt does not use pixels, it places controls in a grid with rows and columns and you need to set up the grid first.

Anyway, I recommend to start with Python stuff first.